# How to make chosen options in a form change colour

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have an HTML code like this:

```
<center>
  <form action="" method="get"> 
    <input style="display:inline" type="hidden" name="srtby" value="updated"> 
    <input style="display:inline" type="hidden" name="srtdir" value="desc"> 
    <input style="display:inline" type="hidden" name="__filelist_page" value="1">
    <img src="/i/i5/fs.png" alt="">
    <input style="border:1px solid #ffffff; border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;width:5em" type="search" name="fltr" value="">
    <input style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important" type="submit" value="Search"> 
    <br>
    <a style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;color:#0f0 !important" href="?srtby=updated&amp;srtdir={_$srtdir|}&amp;fltr=&amp;prpg=10&amp;__filelist_page=1" title="Updated"><b>Updated</b></a> 
    <a style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;" href="?srtby=name&amp;srtdir={_$srtdir|}&amp;fltr=&amp;prpg=10&amp;__filelist_page=1" title="Name"><b>Name</b></a> . <a style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;" href="?srtby=size&amp;srtdir={_$srtdir|}&amp;fltr=&amp;prpg=10&amp;__filelist_page=1" title="Size"><b>Size</b></a> . <a style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;" href="?srtby=type&amp;srtdir={_$srtdir|}&amp;fltr=&amp;prpg=10&amp;__filelist_page=1" title="type"><b>Type</b></a><br>        <a style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;" href="?srtby={_$srtby|}&amp;srtdir=asc&amp;fltr=&amp;prpg=10&amp;__filelist_page=1" title="Ascending"><b>Ascending</b></a>
    <a style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;color:#0f0 !important" href="?srtby={_$srtby|}&amp;srtdir=desc&amp;fltr=&amp;prpg=10&amp;__filelist_page=1" title="Descending"><b>Descending</b></a> 
    <br>
    <select style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important;" name="prpg"> 
      <option>3</option> <option>5</option> 
      <option selected="selected" class="selected">10</option> 
      <option>20</option>
      <option>50</option> 
      <option value="">all</option> 
   </select>
   <input style="border:1px solid #ffffff;border-radius:2px;background:#3b5998;color:#ffffff;padding:0 1px !important;margin: 1px !important;font-size:.75em;text-decoration:none !important" type="submit" value="Per Page">
 </form>
```

All I want is for the chosen options to change colour when they are clicked on and go to their respective pages. I want to see the colour change in the pages they are linked to. I have done some research and have tried JavaScripts but none seem to work.

Comment: When do you want them to change color?  What event should cause it?  Why are you using inline styling?  Have you tried anything yet?  What research have you done?

Comment: I want them to change colour when they are clicked on and go to their respective pages I want to see the colour change in the pages they are linked to. I have done some research. I have tried javascripts but none seem to work

Comment: I have added the clarification that you had provided in comments into the question itself. It is always better to edit the question and add the clarifications there rather than add them in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class ~"selected" to  the option which you want to select on the new page and then apply css to change the color of the option field.

```
    <option class="selected">Example</option>

    select#one{
       color:red;
    }
    select#one option:not(.selected){
       color:blue;
   }
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sygn/9442k00w/3)

Comment: Ok so it dosent work. I was wrong when you click an option it dosent open in a new page it just modifies the one you are in.  You can see what I mean when implement it on my mobile site here http://futuristic.xtgem.com/Apps/Java%20Games/320x240

Comment: @Dami So you want to redirect to another page when a user changes the selection?

Comment: Um no ok look the page is a file list showing all files that i have uploaded page so those options are to sort by and direction so when a user clicks on one of them it sorts the files by the requested order on the page with the modified file list it adds get variables to end of url but it is still the same page. So when a user clicks one of the buttons i just want the colour to change when it goes to modified page

Comment: @Dami You must apply the selected class to the right option. You must do that on the backend, because your page refreshes everytime when you click on the button 'perpage'. You can use the request parameter 'prpg=20' to know on which option element to apply the selected class.